# Ionic Android app works but not apk when installed

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, apk

My app works in browser with `ionic serve`. It works when emulated on device using USB debugging, however it fails when the APK is installed.

The splash screen comes up then a static (links cant be clicked) version of the side bar comes up.

Here is my `index.html` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

     <!-- compiled css output -->
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

   

    
    

    <style type="text/css">
      .platform-ios .manual-ios-statusbar-padding{
        padding-top:20px;
      }
      .manual-remove-top-padding{
        padding-top:0px; 
      }
      .manual-remove-top-padding .scroll{
        padding-top:0px !important;
      }
      ion-list.manual-list-fullwidth div.list, .list.card.manual-card-fullwidth {
        margin-left:-10px;
        margin-right:-10px;
      }
      ion-list.manual-list-fullwidth div.list > .item, .list.card.manual-card-fullwidth > .item {
        border-radius:0px;
        border-left:0px;
        border-right: 0px;
      }
    </style>

    <!--link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/ionic-material/dist/ionic.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-material/dist/ionic.material.min.js"></script-->

   



    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>

    
    <script src="lib/ionicuirouter/ionicUIRouter.js"></script>

     <script src="lib/satellizer/dist/satellizer.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/satellizer/dist/satellizer.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-permission/dist/angular-permission.js"></script>
    

    <!--chat feature-->
   
    <script src="lib/angular-elastic/elastic.js"></script>
    <!--link href="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.14/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.14/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script--> 
    <!-- moment -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
    <!-- angular moment -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/0.8.2/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
     <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <!--script src="lib/Autolinker.js/dist/Autolinker.js"></script-->
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>

     <!--socket io client library-->
    <!--script src="http://chat.socket.io/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script-->

    <!-- Other Libraries-->
    <script src="lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <!--script src="lib/angular-socket-io/socket.js"></script-->


   

  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" animation="slide-left-right-ios7" ng-strict-di >
  <div>
    <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false" data-componentid="side-menu21" >
        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-nav-bar class="bar-calm" >
                <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
                <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
                </ion-nav-buttons>
            </ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-side-menu side="left" id="side-menu21" style=''>
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-calm">
                <div class="title">Menu</div>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content padding="false" class="side-menu-left has-header">
                <ion-list id="menu-list3" class=" " data-componentid="list3">
                    <ion-item class="item-divider " id="menu-list-item-divider1" data-componentid="list-item-divider1">General</ion-item>
                </ion-list>
                <ion-list id="menu-list4" class=" " data-componentid="list4">
                    <ion-item id="menu-list-item10" ui-sref="home2.places" menu-close="" class="icon item item-icon-left" data-componentid="list-item10"><i class="icon ion-map"></i> Home</ion-item>
                    
                    <ion-item  class="icon item item-icon-left " id="menu-list-item23" menu-close="" ui-sref="home2.inbox" data-componentid="list-item23"><i class="icon ion-chatboxes"></i>Inbox</ion-item>
                    <ion-item  class="icon item item-icon-left" id="menu-list-item23" menu-close="" ui-sref="login" data-componentid="list-item23"> Login</ion-item>
                   
                </ion-list>
                <ion-list id="menu-list5" class=" " data-componentid="list5">
                    <ion-item class="item-divider " id="menu-list-item-divider4" data-componentid="list-item-divider4">App Info</ion-item>
            
                    <ion-item id="menu-list-item19" ui-sref="about" class="icon item item-icon-left" menu-close="" data-componentid="list-item19">About</ion-item>
                   
                    <ion-item id="menu-list-item21" ui-sref="policy" class="icon item item-icon-left" menu-close="" data-componentid="list-item21">Privacy Policy</ion-item>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`config.xml` snippet

```html
 <widget id="com.fdfdfdjhgvhy655565656ytyytytrtrt85656" version="1.1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="70000"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="9000"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="3000"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
</widget>
```

Not sure what other info might be needed. Can anyone please help me?

Tried `jsconsole.com` and got this:

```js
file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17697link
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularMoment due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angularMoment' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/nomod?p0=angularMoment
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13380:12
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15270:17
    at ensure (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15194:38)
    at module (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15268:14)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17674:22
    at forEach (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13648:20)
    at loadModules (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17658:5)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17675:40
    at forEach (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13648:20)
    at loadModules (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17658:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=angularMoment&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'angularMoment'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.3%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DangularMoment%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13380%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A15270%3A17%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A15194%3A38)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20module%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A15268%3A14)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17674%3A22%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13648%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17658%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17675%3A40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13648%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17658%3A5)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13380:12
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17697:15
    at forEach (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13648:20)
    at loadModules (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17658:5)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17675:40
    at forEach (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13648:20)
    at loadModules (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17658:5)
    at createInjector (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17584:11)
    at doBootstrap (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14942:20)
    at bootstrap (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14963:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20Failed%20to%20instantiate%20module%20angularMoment%20due%20to%3A%0AError%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'angularMoment'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.3%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DangularMoment%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13380%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A15270%3A17%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A15194%3A38)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20module%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A15268%3A14)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17674%3A22%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13648%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17658%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17675%3A40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13648%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17658%3A5)%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.3%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DangularMoment%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520Module%2520'angularMoment'%2520is%2520not%2520available!%2520You%2520either%2520misspelled%2520the%2520module%2520name%2520or%2520forgot%2520to%2520load%2520it.%2520If%2520registering%2520a%2520module%2520ensure%2520that%2520you%2520specify%2520the%2520dependencies%2520as%2520the%2520second%2520argument.%250Ahttp%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.3%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DangularMoment%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520file%253A%252F%252F%252Fandroid_asset%252Fwww%252Flib%252Fionic%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.js%253A13380%253A12%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520file%253A%252F%252F%252Fandroid_asset%252Fwww%252Flib%252Fionic%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.js%253A15270%253A17%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520ensure%2520(file%253A%252F%252F%252Fandroid_asset%252Fwww%252Flib%252Fionic%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.js%253A15194%253A38)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520module%2520(file%253A%252F%252F%252Fandroid_asset%252Fwww%252Flib%252Fionic%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.js%253A15268%253A14)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520file%253A%252F%252F%252Fandroid_asset%252Fwww%252Flib%252Fionic%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.js%253A17674%253A22%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520forEach%2520(file%253A%252F%252F%252Fandroid_asset%252Fwww%252Flib%252Fionic%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.js%253A13648%253A20)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520loadModules%2520(file%253A%252F%252F%252Fandroid_asset%252Fwww%252Flib%252Fionic%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.js%253A17658%253A5)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520file%253A%252F%252F%252Fandroid_asset%252Fwww%252Flib%252Fionic%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.js%253A17675%253A40%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520forEach%2520(file%253A%252F%252F%252Fandroid_asset%252Fwww%252Flib%252Fionic%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.js%253A13648%253A20)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520loadModules%2520(file%253A%252F%252F%252Fandroid_asset%252Fwww%252Flib%252Fionic%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.js%253A17658%253A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13380%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17697%3A15%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13648%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17658%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17675%3A40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13648%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17658%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17584%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A14942%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20bootstrap%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A14963%3A12)
file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17697
```

Answer (score 0):

I never faced this issue but I think it's because the navigator doesn't load properly javascript files (probably an undefined called) so the application stops while before ending the loading.

Anyway, the best thing to do to find out the issue is to have access to your console even on your device. There are many things for this but the best is probably https://jsconsole.com/ (it redirect your device logs into a remote console)

Comment: This is an AngularJS error. It means the module 'angularMoment' is missing.
i don't know if you are using it or if it is a ionic dependance but anyway, just find the min.js file for the module and add it to your app.

( https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/blob/master/angular-moment.min.js )

Comment: I had it in. was being reference from an external repo. I removed that and added it using bower and its still giving the error. when I remove 'angularMoments' from the module everything works except the time-ago feature

Comment: yea I know the procedure, it worked in the browser but gave the error when compiled and install as apk